# How to manage Model, Manager and QuerySet?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-managers

If each of `Model` objects has many `Manager` and `QuerySet`, it causes my `models.py` to be unreadable and so long. How do I manage them?

I come up with a solution. Originally. `Model`, `Manager` and `QuerySet` are in `models.py`. I want to separate from them and make independent files, for example, `managers.py`, `queryset.py`.

This is my original directory.

```
├── views.py
├── urls.py
├── models.py
└── ...
```

This is new directory by my method.

```
├── views.py
├── urls.py
├── models.py
├── managers.py
├── queryset.py
└── ...
```

Is is okay? or anyone has better propose?

Comment: Thats actually a nice approach when you have lots of code for custom managers.

Comment: This is quite arbitrary, you should do whatever works best for _you_. Both your approach and François' approach are valid solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally prefer to split the `models.py` file if it's too long.

Delete `models.py`, create a director instead. Under the folder `models`

- `__init__.py` - with the includes:

  - `from .group1 import Model1, Model2`
  - `from .group2 import Model3, Model4`
- `group1.py` - contains `Model1`, `Model1QuerySet`, `Model2`, `Model2QuerySet`
- `group2.py` - contains `Model3`, etc.

---

Obviously you want some nice meaningful names instead of `group1` & `group2`.

Comment: Why not: `group1.py` contains `Model1`, `Model1QuerySet`, `group2.py` contains `Model2`, `Model2QuerySet`, etc.

Comment: You could but I think that would make a LOT of files. Also you probably have models that belong together.

Comment: What is LOT? May you explain it?

Comment: I just meant a *lot* :)